# String parsing in optimal way

Tags: string, parsing

Suppose I have a string as `onehhhtwominusthreehhkkseveneightjnine`
Now I want to parse this string to get the numbers out of it. For Example this string should return an array, [one,two,minusthree,seven,eight,nine].
The order of the Integers should be maintained.

Can anyone Please suggest an optimal way to do this parsing? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't fully defined the problem. Is "plusthree" acceptable? What about "plus three" or "addone"? If you had "oneplustwo" what would you need to do? Once the problem is fully stated it is easier, i.e. possible, to approach a solution.

Comment: @AndyG This string is without any spaces. plus will not be there. And minusthree represents this integer "-3"

Comment: Can the same number occur more than once? I am getting the impression that you could initially perform nine searches (for "one", "two", etc.), especially if the numbers will appear in order; but I still think there are too many unknowns.

Comment: @AndyG Numbers can appear in any order. It could be ninekkkthreeqqminusfour and also no limit on how many times they can occur. I need to maintain the order in which the numbers exist in string

Answer (score 1):

(You haven't mentioned a programming language?)

I would probably search for "minus" and check the number(s) that follow it. Then search for "one", then "two", noting their indexes. This would provide enough information to map and output the results, and order, that you need.

Another option is to look at each character in order, comparing each to the 10 choices. I couldn't tell you which is the most efficient - I think it depends on the possible total string length. I'd probably write both and profile them.

---

If the string to search is not of inordinate length then I suspect that the second approach might be more efficient. This is because, as soon as you have a match, you can eliminate searching the following (known) length of characters.

That is, if you have "abceightd", once you discover the "e" and its "eight" you can skip four characters. You can also skip the a, b, and c anyway, as they are not the beginning character for any of the 10 choices.

---

I am assuming your choices are:

> one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, minus

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a) you have access to regular expressions in your choice of programming language and b) your possible choices are as *Andy G* has assumed... then this regular expression can pick out the numbers grouped with their associated `minus`, if present:

```
/((?:minus)*(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine))/g
```

Applied to your example string using JavaScript's `RegEx.exec()`, for example, this extracts:

```
one
two
minusthree
seven
eight
nine
```

You could easily place a space after any `minus` matched if required. Does this help at all?